# How can I use sugar.js to search arrays in objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, sugar.js

I have an array of objects. Each object is a municipality, with it's name, an alternate spelling, and an identifying number.

```
var munis = [
    {
        name: 'St. Louis Hills',
        alt: 'Saint Louis Hills',
        nhdNum: 992
    },
    {
        name: 'Mount Pleasant',
        alt: 'Mt. Pleasant',
        nhdNum: 1004
    }
];
```

In my application, users can type a name. Then I use Sugar.js to search this array and return the particular object which matches what they typed, like this:

```
var theMatch = munis.find(function(el) { 
    return el.name === userInput || el.alt === userInput; 
});
```

This works well, but only allows me to use one canonical name and one alternate spelling. I'd like to have multiple alternates, like this:

```
{
    name: 'Mount Pleasant',
    alt: ['Mt. Pleasant','Mt Pleasant'],
    nhdNum: 1004
}
```

But I can't figure out how to adapt Sugar's .find() to search this structure. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't know sugar.js but it appears that .find() takes a function.  I'm guessing this function can do anything, it doesn't need to be a single return statement with a boolean expression.  So write a for loop and iterate over the list.

Comment: Someone took your advice and posted an algorithm not long after your comment. A modified version of that worked for me. Alas, the person deleted their answer and now I can't accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Array::indexOf` :

```
var theMatch = munis.find(function(el) { 
   return el.name === userInput ||
     el.alt.indexOf(userInput) > -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested find function:

```
var theMatch = munis.find(function(el) { 
    return el.name === userInput || el.alt.find(userInput); 
});
```

If you use indexOf it will return the index only but this will return the object containing the value.